# Duplicate Excel rows loading to table

Tags: ssis

I have a Data Flow Task inside a Foreach loop. It works fine and It does load all the Excel files. However, the problem is, It loads each File 3 or 4 times which obviously will cause duplicates in data

Comment: When you open Excel destination, You will find the option for Overwrite the file, check that. (In the case of your files that load each time have the same data.)

Comment: I load the data to a sql destination. I only use Excel for the source

Answer (score 0):

Load the data to a staging table, and then run a stored procedure that moves the data from the staging table to the destination table and removes the duplicates in the process.